# new Date() always returns local date....how to get Date object in utc?

Tags: reactjs, date, local, utc, react-datepicker

I retrieve UTC date string from backend in form: `2020-02-16T22:00:00Z`
To use new version of `react-datepicker`, dates should be converted into JS Date object (because it doesn't work with moment anymore)....otherwise datepicker throws `Invalid date` error.

So, before passing date to datepicker's `selected` prop, I must do this:

`let date = new Date(utcDateStringFromBackend)` but then, `date` becomes local, CEST date object (in my case +1h hour): `Sun Feb 16 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`

How to get js Date object in UTC?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC). If you want to get the date in UTC.

```
let date = "Sun Feb 16 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0100"
console.log(new Date(date).toUTCString())
```

outputs **Sun, 16 Feb 2020 22:00:00 GMT**

Comment: Same comment as below, I DON'T NEED date string, I NEED date object but with date in UTC...

Answer (score 0):

```
  new Date(new Date().toUTCString()).toISOString()
```

Comment: At least, read topic title next time. `How to get Date object...?` Then read the rest: `To use new version of react-datepicker, dates should be converted into JS Date object (because it doesn't work with moment anymore).`
I can't use strings, I need JS Date object but in UTC time.

Comment: Oh sorry, i couldn't understand it before. See my edited answer if it can help you